# pegar arquivos xml em uma aplicação Java

Tags: php, java, xml

Oi, sou novo em programação, estou estagiando em uma empresa de Ti e preciso fazer uma aplicação em java que pega arquivos .xml gerados num sistema em php de consultas médicas e os disponibilizam em uma lista que esteja sempre atualizada a cada consulta registrada. Não sei por onde começar. Alguém pode me ajudar ficarei agradecido. Isso pode me garantir um emprego na empresa futuramente.

Comment: Primeiro você deve saber trabalhar com XML no Java, provavelmente    você usurá Java web, onde você fará a leitura do conteúdo XML e listaria todos os dados. Sugiro que dê uma olhada nesses links: http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-xml-design-patterns/trabalhando-com-xml/#4-4-xstream | http://www.devmedia.com.br/manipulando-arquivos-xml-em-java/3245

Comment: Obrigado, vou estudar um pouco. (y)